# RxJava 1.2.6 Use results from one method to call 2 additional methods sequentially

Tags: rx-java

I currently have `getTeams` which returns an array of teamIds. In order to call `getTeams`, I have to get the credentials by calling `authbus.getAuth()`. Here is the code:

```
public Observable<WebResponse<Team>> getTeams() {
    return authbus.getAuth().take(1).flatMap((UserInfo info) ->
            webApi.getTeams("Bearer " + info.getTokenSet().getAccessToken())
    );
}
```

But now I need to take the result of `getTeams` and call `getTeam` and pass in the first TeamId. The problem is that I need to pass in the auth tokens into `getTeam` just like I did for `getTeams`.  How can I chain a call to `getTeam` that accepts a token from `getAuth` and a teamId from `getTeams`?

For background info, the API is changing behind the scenes. The old API returned all the team data that I need by calling `getTeam`, but the new API is split between 2 calls - `getTeams` to get an array of teams and then call `getTeam(teamId)` to get the details for the team. Right now we will only ever get 1 team from `getTeams`, so I'd like to automatically call `getTeam(teamId)` in 1 place so that I don't have to update several different places in code. Down the road, they will be updating the UI to loop through every team and call `getTeam(teamId)` for each of them. This will require a fairly substantial app change, so at that time the code can be changed to call `getTeam` for every team.

Here is my attempt at coding it, which does not compile:

```
public Observable<WebResponse<Team>> getTeams() {
    return authbus.getAuth().take(1).flatMap((UserInfo info) ->
        webApi.getTeams("Bearer " + info.getTokenSet().getAccessToken()).take(1).flatMap((Teams teams) ->
                 webApi.getTeam(info.getTokenSet().getAccessToken(), teams.getTeamIds()[0])
        ));
    }
```

Edit: Here's the second attempt. It complains about "can't infer functional interface type"

```
public Observable<WebResponse<Team>> getTeam() {
        return authbus.getAuth().take(1).flatMap((UserInfo info) ->
                webApi.getTeams("Bearer " + info.getTokenSet().getAccessToken()).take(1).<Teams>flatMap((Teams teams) ->
                        webApi.getTeam(info.getTokenSet().getAccessToken(), teams.getTeamIds()[0])
                ));
}
```

Comment: What's the compile error message? I think it may because compiler can't infer the generic type, try add explicit generic by <>.

Comment: @DeanXu Yes, cannot infer functional interface type. What is the syntax for adding explicit generic type? I tried .flatMap<Teams>((Teams teams) -> but that isn't correct.

Comment: method generic declaration should be `.<Teams>flatMap(...)`

Comment: @DeanXu I added it but it didn't help. Same error at the same spot. See edit above.

Comment: If you have problems with generic try to pass anonimous class instead of lambda, in case of "(Teams teams) -> {}".